# submit returns model as null in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send the data in the partial view to the controller on submit, but it is sent as null.

here is the code of the view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.mylist

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>custlist</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", new AjaxOptions() {
        UpdateTargetId = "custlist" })) 

    {
        <div>
            <p>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("el1", Model.Emplist);}
            </p>
            <p>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("clist", Model.Custlist);}
            </p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

This method is used to call the view with the model being passed

```
public ActionResult custlist()
        {
            List<Employee> Emplist = new List<Employee>() {
            new Employee(){ ID = "1", Name = "A"},
            new Employee(){ ID = "2", Name = "B"},
            new Employee(){ ID = "3", Name = "C"},
            };
            List<Customer> CustList = new List<Customer>() {
            new Customer(){ CustID = "1", CustName = "X"},
            new Customer(){ CustID = "2", CustName = "Y"},
            new Customer(){ CustID = "3", CustName = "Z"},
            };
            mylist m = new mylist();
            m.Emplist = Emplist;
            m.Custlist = CustList;
            return View(m);
        }
```

below method is getting called on submit, but the model object f is received as null.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(mylist f)
    {
        return View(f);
    }
```

Comment: Posted data and how the modelbinder handles it has everything to do with the generated field names in the HTML document. You've neither posted that nor the contents of your partials which hold all the form fields, so there's no way to tell what the problem may be. It would also be helpful to see the class definition for `mylist` (horrible class name, BTW) and any ancillary classes such as those that likely make up your `Custlist` and `Emplist` properties.

Comment: Your creating partials based separate properties of model `mylist` which means the controls will not be named correctly and wont post back to model `mylist`. Also your `Ajax.BeginForm` method has `UpdateTargetId = "custlist"` but you don't have an element with that `id`.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick question, are you using foreach for the loop? if so use the normal, try with this

```
  for(int index=0; index < Model.Emplist.Count; index++)
  {
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Emplist[index].ID)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Emplist[index].Name)
  }
```